# WinForms toolbar office like

Tags: .net, wpf, components, office-2007

which component in Visual Studio 2010 gives me the same "blue" toolbar/tabs as in Office 2007?
Do I need to use WinForms or it is some new WPF component?

Thanks in advance.

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Called the [Ribbon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribbon_%28computing%29), see this [page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2bfc3187-74aa-4154-a670-76ef8bc2a0b4&displaylang=en).

Comment: And it's WPF only or it can be used also with WinForms?

Comment: There seems to be a [WinForms Ribbon on Codeplex](http://windowsribbon.codeplex.com/).